# Serving a page to any URL that ends in its slug

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

Still new to WordPress, so please go easy on me.

**Goal:**

Prevent users of a specific role from viewing other custom post types made by users of same role.

**Intended solution:**

Modify the URL and redirect to a custom 403 page when the user ID doesn't match the post author. As such, if the person attempting to view *example.com/%taxonomy%/%private-post-slug%* would instead be redirected to *example.com/%taxonomy%/403*

**Current redirect code:**

```php
​<?php

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'private_posts_redirect');

function private_posts_redirect() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $post = get_post();
    $author = $post->post_author;
    if( get_post_type() == 'custom-post-type'){
        if(!$user->ID == $author || !$user->ID == 1){
           $intendedtarget = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
           $intendedtargetpath = parse_url( $intendedtarget, PHP_URL_PATH );
           $intendedtargetslug = pathinfo( $intendedtargetpath, PATHINFO_BASENAME );
           $redirectslug = '403';
           $redirecturl = str_replace( $intendedtargetslug, $redirectslug, $intendedtarget);
           wp_redirect($redirect_url);
           exit;
        }
    }
}
```

**Current issue:**

I've created a 403 page with '403' as the slug, I'm just not sure how to serve the content of that template page on any page that ends with that slug.

**Tentative solution:**

```php
add_action('init' '403_page')

function 403_page(){
    if(stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'403')){
        DO_SOMETHING
    }
}
```

I know this only addresses the post author, I've already got the redirects for users that aren't of the role I'm looking to isolate posts for. Additionally, I am using the  Advanced Post Queries plugin to only serve authors their posts, however that doesn't prevent them from viewing others posts by typing random numbers into the URL and getting to view sensitive RFQ, quote, and pricing info that's unique to that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prevent user from viewing any posts that he/she is not the author for, You should first get the post author ID, You can get the author ID of the post by adding the following few lines to single.php file in your current theme:

```
global $post,$current_user;
$author_id = $post->post_author;

if($current_user->ID != $author_id && !current_user_can('administrator')){
// Do whatever you want to do here
exit;
}
```

Note:
The previous code checks if the user is not administrator and also not the author of the current post, You can use wp_safe_redirect(), or PHP header() function to redirect them anywhere else.

Thanks!

Comment: It's wordpress, you should use wp_safe_redirect() over header()

Comment: Yes, That's why I mentioned it first. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the admin still needs to be able to read all posts made by users of that role, as the admin will be providing the quotes to the author. As for redirecting users that aren't the author, I'd like to serve an error page at the base URL, as the error page has a button to go back to the referring page. If I redirect to another page, they have to go back through their dashboard to get to the previous page they were on, otherwise they'll be stuck in a redirect loop.

Comment: I'll admit, the way you get the data I'm working with is much more elegant, however, I'm still no closer to serving the page located at example.com/403-error/ at another location such as example.com/quotes/403-error when a user that is not the post author attempts to view example.com/quotes/quote-435218

Comment: You can create a specific error template to be displayed for the users who have no access to the page and include it instead of the redirections in the same page, You also can create a new page and place a shortcode there that will handle the error and also have the actions/anchors you need to show, You can do this in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the olny issue but this line:

```
 if(!$user->ID == $author || !$user->ID == 1){
```

should be:

```
 if($user->ID !== $author || $user->ID !== 1){
```

Comment: Ah yeah, I missed that, luckily it's an easy fix. I was using equals to test the if statement and I forgot to change it back to not equals. Any suggestions on where to start on the second bit, other than the fact that the function name can't start with an integer? Would it be an include? A query modifier? Something else entirely?